# React router v5 create a path with two optional params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How to create a path that can handle zero, one, the other or both parameters at once.

For example:

`/offers`
`/offers/q-shoes`
`/offers/London`
`/offers/London/q-shoes`

I am trying to achieve it this way, unfortunately in this case the path `/offers/London` is not captured

```
import React from 'react';
import pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Home, Browse } from './Pages';

const re = pathToRegexp('/offers/:location?/q-:search?');

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={re}>
        <Browse />
      </Route>
     
      <Route path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Those are not parameters. They are paths. URL parameters start with "?" or "&". So your answer is in the question. Since they are already paths, route all of those paths to the same component.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson ok, but based on this I want to extract the parameters in the browse component

Comment: Use the useLocation function from react-router-dom and then do e.g. "const london = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("London");" (assuming that you do "/offers?London=true" or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple paths that lead to the same component:

```
<Route path="/offers/q-shoes">
    <RelevantComponentHere />
</Route>
<Route path="/offers/London">
    <RelevantComponentHere />
</Route>
<Route path="/offers/London/q-shoes">
    <RelevantComponentHere />
</Route>
<Route path="/offers/q-shoes/London">
    <RelevantComponentHere />
</Route>
```

As you can probably tell, this is not ideal. What you could do instead, is to turn the paths into actual URL parameters (e.g. "/offers?q-shoes=true&London=true"). In that case, you only have one path:

```
<Route path="/offers">
    <RelevantComponentHere />
</Route>
```

and you can then use the useParams or the useLocation hook to find the relevant parameters and use them.